# can't download from HttpWebRequest more than once

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am new to C# and trying to write a download manager with HttpWebRequest.
my manager calls a new class for breaking file into chunks for every file and that class calls a new downloader class.

my code for download is:

```
   private void StartDownload()
   {      
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        Console.WriteLine("request");
        request.AddRange((int)_startPos, (int)_endPos);
        WebResponse res = request.GetResponse();         
        Console.WriteLine("res: "+res);
        RequestContentLength = 0;
        try
        {
             bool isFinished = false;
             isDownloading = true;
             double speed = 0;
             using (var responseStream = res.GetResponseStream())
             {
                using (FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Append))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("download started - "+ Url);
                    var buffer = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesRead;
                    DateTime lastDate = DateTime.Now;
                    int lastDownloaded = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0 && isDownloading)
                    {
                       totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                       if ((DateTime.Now - lastDate).TotalSeconds >= 1)
                       {
                           lastDate = DateTime.Now;
                           speed = totalBytesRead - lastDownloaded;
                           lastDownloaded = totalBytesRead;
                        }
                        RequestContentLength += bytesRead;
                        localFileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);                           
                        double percentage = totalBytesRead * 100 / FileHeader.FileSize;
                        onDownloadProgress?.Invoke(ID, fname, percentage, totalBytesRead, FileHeader.FileSize, speed);
                  }
                  isFinished = true;                       
               }
           }
           if (isFinished) {
                    onDownloadFinished?.Invoke(ID, fname, true, "success");
                }
                else
                {
                    onDownloadFinished?.Invoke(ID, fname, false, "error");
                }
                isDownloading = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isDownloading = false;              
                onDownloadFinished?.Invoke(ID, fname, false, ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

the code works fine for the FIRST download ( I cropped the rest to make it shorter) but when I call it after first download I get `Console.WriteLine("request");` to output but the rest stops and after a minute or two I get a timeout error at `WebResponse res = request.GetResponse();` 
I couldn't name my exact problem and couldn't find a solution.
there are some similar posts about this and I tried most of them but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try setting HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout Property

Comment: Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_HttpWebRequest_ReadWriteTimeout link

Comment: @this.girish I set the timeout property to 10 sec and still got the error and second download didnt started

Comment: keep it default just to cross check , The default value is 300,000 milliseconds (5 minutes).

Comment: I set it to 300,000 and it didnt event wait 5 min for System.Net.WebException: 'The operation has timed out'

Comment: i think you need to close/dispose webexception try using this code in catch block catch (WebException ex) {
    DoSomething(ex.Response);
}

Comment: update your code

Comment: @this.girish I dont think the problem is with timeout. at the first download it gets no problem with downloading. when I changed the url for next download it went wrong  I need to close request or response which I tried both